# Build Android support library v4 from source in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-support-library

All the source code is included when downloading the support libraries via SDK manager in Android Studio. Now I need to fix a bug in the support v4 code and add it as a *.jar in my application. But I don't understand how I open and build the source code in Android Studio. Do I import it as a new project? Do I open it as an existing project? What directory is the directory to be imported/opened? Can I just rebuild support-v4 code into a jar?

Thanks!

Comment: Was wondering for the same thing now, please if you get anywhere don't forget to post the response.

Comment: Nothing yet. I did a workaround but still I'm interested in the answer.