# Adding Xamarin support library v4

Tags: android, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

Can you please suggest me how do I manually add xamarin support library v4 jar file to the Components or some other way so that I would be able to use DialogFragment and other features.
The same question has also been asked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27423163/build-android-support-library-v4-from-source-in-android-studio) but no one has proposed the solution.

I am actually working on xamarin using visual studio 2012. I am unable to use DialogFragment and other features because of not proper configuration of xamarin support library v4 in visual studio. I have already installed xamarin support library v4 using sdk manager and it exists in **C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v4**
but visual studio is not loading this library, although it loads automatically. This path contains android-support-v4.jar and src folder as well.

I have also tried installing using nuget but I get the following error

> Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 22.2.1.0'. You
>   are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   'MonoAndroid,Version=v2.2', but  the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

The Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 supports android 1.6 and higher.

I have looked on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915969/error-even-after-installing-andrid-v4-support-library-in-xamarin) but it did not help me.
Thank you.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/2016/05/android-support-repository-and-xamarin-android/ for your reference.